# bloginfo url in javascript

Tags: php, images, javascript, urls

I'm trying to set `<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>` in a variable on Javascript, and then to set `src` of an `img` element, but in the html it's been printed as `src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>"` and not as the actually `url`.

This is how I tried to do it:

`var wpTemplateUrl = "<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>";
primaryImg.src = wpTemplateUrl;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using some API from WordPress itself - https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_localize_script

Comment: That's did it! Thanks :)